# Haskell syntax for instance

Tags: haskell, instances

I'm trying to make a pair an instance of `Printable`, but I can't figure out the correct syntax.
My Printable is this:

```
class Printable a where
    toString :: a -> [Char]

instance Printable Bool where
    toString True = "true"
    toString False = "false"
instance Printable () where
    toString () = "unit type"
```

and my instance for pairs is this:

```
instance  Printable ( a, b ) where
    toString (a,b) = "(" ++ toString a ++ ","++ toString b ++ ")"
```

which, upon compiling, gives me a `No instance for (Printable a) arising from a use of ‘toString’`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, this is a type error, not a syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `a` and `b` to be instances of `Printable`:

```
instance (Printable a, Printable b) => Printable ( a, b ) where
    toString (a,b) = "(" ++ toString a ++ ","++ toString b ++ ")"
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks. I should re-read some things about instances, probably.